# Buffer FID assignment using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, buffer

When buffer analysis is performed on a polygon what determines the order of assignment for FID?
This came up with the following:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(inFC, outFC_50, "50 Meters")
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(outFC_50, outFC_100, [100], "Meters", "Distance", "NONE", "OUTSIDE_ONLY")
```

During the first buffer a polygon goes from FID 5 to 9, not a big deal since there is the added ORIG_FID field. During the second buffer the ORIG_FID is of course the FID from outFC_50. I can join the FID from inFC to outFC_100 and work around it, but I'm curious why the FIDs are changed during a buffer where no dissolving occurs?

Comment: FIDs and OBJECTIDs are controlled by the system.They must be 0 based, contiguous and ascending. In shapefiles edits reorder the FID values so it's not a good idea to trust them to be any value, conversely in geodatabases OBJECTIDs remain the same for the life of a feature (row) and can be trusted (sort of). As a new feature class is created the new IDs start from 0 and increment by 1. Keep what you're doing with the orig_FID (that's how I maintain connectivity between features and their derivatives in shapefiles)

Comment: ^ good point on not trusting FIDs. minor correction OBJECTID's always start from 1 not 0.

Comment: good point about not trusting FIDs. I tried the same using FCs in a GBD and had the same OBJECTID alteration, except ID 6 becomes 10 since as yanes points out it starts at 1. In both cases inFC IDs are continuous and sorted.

Comment: Both FID and OBJECTID fields can be reference by a cursor using the "OID@" field, so the "OID@" field of a cursor can start at 0 or 1, depending on the data source the cursor points to.  So there are situations where you may need to keep track of the data source to know what type of OID@ values are returned and what the starting number is.

Comment: It is a black box where the same programmer could use different optimization techniques based on the processing each tool does.  More likely this is simply a case of two different programmers writing these independently and never synchronizing their code to a common algorithm, or a single programmer trying a new technique on one without going back and revising the other.

Comment: Don't use the FID/ObjectID for your joins - instead create a new field you can populate with whatever ID values you want and can then be transferred as-is to the new feature classes for you to join on.

Comment: FIDs start at different values depending on the datasource and the properties of that datasource,  They should not be trusted for anything other than what ArcGIS trusts them (to be unique).

Comment: These are all good points for working (or not working) with FID/OBJECTID values.. You're on the right path by copying your FID values and making them static - as Vince said they're guaranteed to be unique so can work with attribute joins. Before joining though it's a good idea to index your copy of FID field(s) (unique but not ascending) which will improve the speed of accessing the joined table.

Comment: As far as why the FID is changing on the buffering. This is probably do to the algorithm that ArcGIS is using to perform, which may depend on an spatial index. I wouldn't be surprised if you find that the buffers start in the upper left. I don't know of any documentation that gets that specific. You might be able to see how QGIS does their buffering to get a sense of how ArcGIS' works. You could probably figure it out by experimenting with different arrangements of objects and see which ones get the first FID, or sort your polygons spatially using the Sort_management tool.